# Can I load models into (Ignition) Gazebo from a HTTP server?

Tags: gazebo, gazebo-model, gazebo-ignition, download

Is it possible to load models from the web without running a Fuel server? Is there maybe a protocol that a custom HTTP server can implement, so it can serve files to (Ignition) Gazebo?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If it helps, here is the c++ side in gazebo for downloading models from fuel server: https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-fuel-tools/blob/2670064aac93ee750196cdf722c71048a530b643/src/FuelClient.cc#L660, and the config file is at https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-fuel-tools/blob/gz-fuel-tools8/conf/config.yaml. Here're the fuel server's routes: https://github.com/gazebo-web/fuel-server/blob/main/routes.go.